# How to save PDF from received binary response from axios

Tags: typescript, axios, filesaver.js

I would like to save a PDF from received binary response from axios get.

I'm passing to the request the following headers:

```
const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/pdf',
    responseType: 'arraybuffer',
  },
};
```

I want after receiving the binary response, to download it using file-saver library, specifically its saveAs function

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem the following way:

```
public async report(id: number): Promise<void> {
 const config: AxiosRequestConfig = {
  responseType: 'blob',
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/pdf',
  },
 };

 return axios
  .get(`${BASE_URL}/${id}`, config)
  .catch((error: AxiosError) => axiosErrorsAdapter(error))
  .then((res: AxiosResponse) => {
    FileSaver.saveAs(new Blob([res.data]), `Report_Encargo_${id}.pdf`);
  });
}
```